# remain the value of input after hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an edit function where their is a function that has hide/show if i click edit. My problem is how can i remain the value of row if im going to hide it?

for example i have this dialog

[image]

and decided to edit sample 1(first row)

[image]

and then i decided i realize that i dont want to edit sample 1 then close it (by clicking edit again) then i want to edit sample 5 but i got this error

[image]

here is my **script**

```
//show and hide update button checker
function update_contain(){
    var row = jQuery(".beneficiaries_rows input[type='text']:visible").length;
    if(row > 0){
        jQuery('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("Update")').button().show();
    }else{
        jQuery('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("Update")').button().hide();
        }
    }


//beneficiaries edit
jQuery(".edit_beneficiaries").click(function(){
  var row = jQuery(this).closest(".beneficiaries_rows");
  var show = row.find(".hide");
  var hide = row.find(".show");
  if(jQuery(show).is(":visible")){
    jQuery(show).css({"display":"none"});
    jQuery(hide).css({"display":"inline-block"});
  }else{
    jQuery(hide).css({"display":"none"});
    jQuery(show).css({"display":"inline-block"});
  }
  update_contain();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="border: 2px solid black;margin:auto;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:145px;"><center>Name<center></th>
        <th><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            echo "<tr class='beneficiaries_rows' id='".$row1['id']."' data-id='".$row1['ben_id']."'>";
            echo "<td><input class='hide' type='text' name='bename_update' value='".$row1['name']."'></div>";
            echo "<div class='show'>".$row1['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<center><button class='del_beneficiaries'>X</button><button class='edit_beneficiaries'>Edit</button></center>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

> P.S im not good in english thats why im posting a picture to elaborate
>   my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set the text inside your label with something like this

`jQuery("[selector for your label]").html(jQuery("[selector for input]").val());`

I suggest doing this on click, just before you hide the input.

edit; since you're not really following:

```
jQuery(".edit_beneficiaries").click(function(){
    var row_display = jQuery(this).parents("tr").find(".show");
    var row_edit = jQuery(this).parents("tr").find(".hide");
    jQuery(row_display).html(jQuery(row_edit).val());
});
```

Comment: so im going to put that sir above the **click function?**

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, you should put it in the click function.

Comment: i dont know if it is the correct but i tried this

`var x = jQuery("tr").html(jQuery(".beneficiaries_rows input[type='text']").val());`

Comment: can you elaborate it further sir? i dont really get it

Comment: I've clarified further with some code which will change the value of your div when `$(".edit_beneficiaries")` is clicked. Going any further with an explanation shifts away from your question and into teaching you how to code. I suggest trying some jQuery tutorials, and some tutorials on CSS/jQuery selectors

Comment: thank you sir this is all i need thank you sir i just need a sample code since im not good in english to understand

Comment: I still recommend having a look at some selector tutorials, as your understanding of them is what is letting you down the most with this coding example.

Comment: but i think their is still that i want that if the user input a blank and hide it again i want to automatically replace the blank into given value

Comment: but your code will do i just change the .html into .text